# In MongoDB, how to remove a field with a certain value in all documents that have it?

Tags: mongodb, unset

I have a collection named *employees*

I want to remove all fields that have a null value in all documents inside the *employees* collection.

This is my code in creating the database:

```
db.employees.insertMany( [ {"Name": "Stephen Jackson", "Salary": 16099.55, "Position": "President", 
"Rank": 1, "ReportingTo": null} ] )

db.employees.insertMany( [ {"Name": "Michael Harrison", "Salary": 14567.12, "Position": "Vice- 
President", "Rank": 2, "ReportingTo": "[President]"} ] )

db.employees.insertMany( [ {"Name": "Rex Andres", "Salary": 13891.22, "Position": "Secretary", 
"Rank": 3, "ReportingTo": "[Vice-President]"} ] )

db.employees.insertMany( [ {"Name": "Sam Johnson", "Salary": 13000, "Position": "Treasurer", "Rank": 
4, "ReportingTo": "[Secretary, Vice-President]"} ] )
```

Here is what I tried doing:

```
db.employees.update( {"ReoportingTo": null}, {"$unset": {"ReportingTo": ""}} )
```

I was expecting the field in the first document to be removed since it's the only one with the null value.

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: @JobyWilsonMathews I updated the question. There was no error. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is multiple matches the $unset on null value  will not be successful , you need to unset following way :

Option 1) multi:true:

```
db.employees.update( {"ReoportingTo": null}, {"$unset": {"ReportingTo": ""}} ,{multi:true})
```

Option 2) updateMany:

```
db.employees.updateMany( {"ReoportingTo": null}, {"$unset": {"ReportingTo": ""}} )
```